# Highlight Links on Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I am trying to finish up my navigation for my site.  I'm attaching the jsfiddle code to show you what code I have now.  My problem is my child links become gray when they are suppose to but, I want to make the top level link when I click on that gray as well.  The way I have my pages labeled is like this

Page1
  Page1a
  Page1b
Page2
  Page2a
.
.
.
ETC.

I need Page1 and Page2 to turn gray like the sublevels do.  If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.  Thank you for your time.

http://jsfiddle.net/gUmYP/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#body').ready(function(){
            var URL = location.pathname.split("/");

            URL = URL[URL.length-1];
            //<![CDATA[
            for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++){ // 4 = number of items, if you add more increase it, make number 1 larger than total items.
                if ((URL.indexOf(i) != -1) && (!$('#i'+i).is(':visible'))) {
                    $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                    $('#i'+i).slideDown(0);
                    $('#i'+i)
                        .find('li')
                        .each( function() {
                            var current = $(this).find('a')[0];
                            if (current.href == window.location.href)
                                current.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";

                            current.style.color = "#006";
                        });
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Unfortunately none of the answers below have solved my issue, some have made it so the parent link now highlights, but it makes the other features not work correctly.  I need the menu to still highlight in yellow when I hover over everything, I need the submenus to still be the light blue when not active, and I need all active links(parent or child) to show the gray highlight that they are the active link.  Does anyone know the solution to fix all those issues?

Answer for this problem can be found at this post...
[Active Link on javascript menu to work on parent link not just child link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000789/active-link-on-javascript-menu-to-work-on-parent-link-not-just-child-link)

Comment: This is done by css, no?

Comment: some js will be required since he wants a click and change. I am sure this will involve parent() somewhere

Comment: Only page 1 and 2? not all of them?

Comment: if you have a better way I can do this with CSS, id love to see it.  and I want all the pages that why its ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

I redid your jQuery as it seemed overly complicated. Take a look at the result on this jsfiddle and let me know if that's what you were going for!

```
$("#nav > li").click(function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(".selected").children("ul").slideToggle();
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    $(".selected").children("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PBKxy/

Comment: the submenus don't get highlighted now with this.  and it seems to close the menu when its not suppose to.

Comment: check out my new edit.. the submenu still highlights in yellow and the accordion should act as expected

Comment: 1.  i need all the child links too to be gray and it closes after second click

Comment: So you want the child links gray and not the parent link? To do that, just target .selected ul li a {} in your CSS

Comment: no i need the active link gray, regardless if its parent of child.

Comment: To determine if it is the active link, the easiest way would be to add a class name to the link in your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gUmYP/16/

```
$('#nav li a').each(function(){
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#006');
            $(this).css('color', '#CCC');
        });
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#ccc');
        $(this).css('color', '#066');
```

Comment: this is close, just kills the colors on the child links that we lighter blue before.

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure that your control logic that decides in which menu item will be re-colored at what time needs some review, therefore i only changed the code to actually change the colors below. [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUmYP/32/) that demonstrates the effect hard-coded on menu item #2.

note that if `location.pathname` ends with a `/` you probably want refer to the element `URL[URL.length-2]` instead of `URL[URL.length-1]`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#body').ready(function(){
            var URL = location.pathname.split("/");

            URL = URL[URL.length-1];
            //<![CDATA[
            for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++){ // 4 = number of items, if you add more increase it, make number 1 larger than total items.
                if ((URL.indexOf(i) != -1) && (!$('#i'+i).is(':visible'))) {
                    $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                    $('#i'+i).slideDown(0);
                    $('#i'+i)
                        .find('li')
                        .each( function(idx, ex) {
                            var current = $(ex).find('a');
                            if (current.href == window.location.href) {
                                current.css({
                                      backgroundColor: '#ccc'
                                    , color:           '#006'
                                });
                                $('#i'+i).prev('a').css({
                                      backgroundColor: '#ccc'
                                    , color:           '#006'
                                });
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```