# Active Link on javascript menu to work on parent link not just child link

Tags: javascript, css, navigationbar

I am trying to finish up my navigation for my site.  I'm attaching the jsfiddle code to show you what code I have now.  My problem is my child links become gray when they are suppose to but, I want to make the top level link when I click on that gray as well.  The way I have my pages labeled is like this

```
Page1
  Page1a
  Page1b
Page2
  Page2
.
.
.
ETC.
```

I need Page1 and Page2 to turn gray like the sublevels do.  If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.  Thank you for your time.

http://jsfiddle.net/gUmYP/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#body').ready(function(){
            var URL = location.pathname.split("/");

            URL = URL[URL.length-1];
            //<![CDATA[
            for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++){ // 4 = number of items, if you add more increase it, make number 1 larger than total items.
                if ((URL.indexOf(i) != -1) && (!$('#i'+i).is(':visible'))) {
                    $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                    $('#i'+i).slideDown(0);
                    $('#i'+i)
                        .find('li')
                        .each( function() {
                            var current = $(this).find('a')[0];
                            if (current.href == window.location.href)
                                current.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";

                            current.style.color = "#006";
                        });
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Previous question was here, but was never answered fully:
[Highlight Links on Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835218/highlight-links-on-navigation)

Unfortunately none of the answers below have solved my issue, some have made it so the parent link now highlights, but it makes the other features not work correctly.  I need the menu to still highlight in yellow when I hover over everything, I need the submenus to still be the light blue when not active, and I need all active links(parent or child) to show the gray highlight that they are the active link.  Does anyone know the solution to fix all those issues?

Comment: I don't see any gray highlight in your fiddle, is that gray background? gray text?

Comment: weird not sure why its not working there.  if you go to my website and find a menu that has sublinks you'll see what I mean.  I'll try and fix the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eUZ5/).

```
$('#nav li a').click(
   (...)

   // Here I removed the "active" class from all siblings "li"
   $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");

   (...)

   // Here I add the "active" class to this "li"
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");

   (...)
)
```

Note 1: The new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eUZ5/4/)

Comment: I think that's what the OP is looking for, it'd be nice to explain what's wrong with their approach

Comment: almost.  What I need is the active current page link to have a background of #ccc vs. the #506ab3.

Comment: I think I am not understanding the final result, is it like this [Link]?(http://imgbin.org/images/14649.png)

Comment: exactly.  it should look like that when you click on the board of education link.  when you go to educational phil. that should turn gray and the board of education color should go back to the color it was.

Comment: Look my answer again, I added a note with the new JSFiddle, you can try the new version.

Comment: I copied the different javascript and the css to my site but it doesn't change anything for some reason.

Comment: maybe it's some cache, can you share the link for your site?

Comment: I think I got the answer, the problem is in your site you are pointing to other ".shtml". On these files you need to add the class "active" to the related "li". For example in "district2.shtml" you have to put the class on the "li" related to "Boad Of Education"

Comment: yea I see what you are saying, but since I use ssi files for this, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Does not the content of your ssi file cover lateral menu?

Comment: unfortunately not sure what you mean by this.  This is my first website.

Comment: I wanna know the content of any of your ssi file

Comment: my fiddle is pretty much my sidenavdistrict.html if that helps.  the css somes from district1.shtml

Comment: How do you set "display: block" to the specific "ul"?

Comment: #nav li a {
 display: block;  that's the only display:block I have.

Comment: When I clicked in a top menu, like "Board of Education" the page "district2.shtml" will be loaded. I wanna know how you set "display: block" in the related tag: '<ul id="i2" style="display: block;">'

Comment: if you scroll up and look at the code in my question.  im pretty sure all that stuff is done in the javascript.

Comment: Yeahh now we understand ourselves =D. Try above this line: "$('#i'+i).slideDown(0);" put the following code: "$('#i'+i).parent().addClass("active");"

Comment: ok this somewhat worked, but it doesn't allow board of education to expand.

Comment: yes, should I use my normal nav.js or should I use the edits that you made?

Comment: Just add the code I said, you must don't remove the code "$('#i'+i).slideDown(0);". So add back your removed code, and it will work

Comment: 99% there.  Is there a way to not have the parent stay highlighted, I just need the current page its on.  The parent should only be highlighted when that page is selected.

Comment: I didn't understand what you wish, can you explain with some example?

Comment: when you click on board of education it drops down a submenu and board of education gets highlighted.  but if I click on educational philosophy id like that to be highlighted and board of education to be unhighlighted.  so the parent doesn't stay highlighted, just the active page is highlighted.

Comment: Lookt at this code, change the JS, and make the little change in the CSS: http://pastebin.com/CfS15SgA

Comment: now 99.9% the active color is yellow, but I just want that for just hovering.  I would like the gray with blue letters for the active highlight.  I think its just a css issue now.

Comment: You are welcome, good luck for you, you don't give up easy, that is nice.